# PHP preg_match pattern is substring of subject

Tags: php, substring, preg-match

I want to test if an input is of the type 1234567 (7 digits). 
I use

```
preg_match($pattern,$subject);
```

where

```
$pattern = '/^[0-9]{7}$/';
```

However I get 1 for the case where the subject is

```
L-8987765
```

Which I do not want. How can I overcome this?

```
   function isDocid($documento_id)
      {
       $subject = pg_escape_literal($documento_id);
       $pattern1 = '/^[0-9]{7}$/';

            if (preg_match($pattern1, $subject) === 1) 
            {
            return 1;
            }
            else
            {
            return 0;
            }}

$test_carta = isDocid('L-8987765');
echo('<p> ja existe docid   '. $test_carta  .'</p>');
```

I am expecting:
        ja existe docid      0

Comment: Check the return type of [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) This test returns 0 https://3v4l.org/6AqKR Is there more code to it?

Comment: yes, there is code. I am going to edit the question

Comment: Can you also add to the question what you expect from it?

Comment: After a few edits, here is the code I am dealing with

Comment: If I run the code without `pg_escape_literal` I get `0` See https://3v4l.org/FtRkX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-literal.php) (italics are mine):

> **`pg_escape_literal()`** escapes a literal for querying the PostgreSQL database. It returns an escaped literal in the PostgreSQL format. **`pg_escape_literal()`** *adds quotes before and after data*.

In other words, you were never going to get a positive result from your regular expression check because of the quotes in the way. Don't use database escapes until you are ready to insert data into a database query. Or, better yet, don't insert a PHP variable into a database query – use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php) instead.

```
function isDocid($documento_id)
{
   return (preg_match('/^[0-9]{7}$/', $documento_id) === 1) ? 1 : 0;
}

$test_carta = isDocid('L-8987765');
echo('<p> ja existe docid   '. $test_carta  .'</p>');
```